# Stored data apparently vanishes without warning

Tags: sql-server, vb6, persistence, crud, sql-server-2000

**Abstract:** CRUD queries are not being reliably persisted in my VB6 + SQL 2000 application, resulting in loss of data. How/What do I change to fix the behavior ? I'm okay with both always persist or showing errors when not persisting, but at the moment the issue happens *silently*.

I'm not sure about what pieces of the source to include here, I welcome suggestions.

**Details:**

I inherited a *very old (20 years+)* desktop application, written in VB6 and using a SQL 2000 database to store its data.

It seems that sometimes (no clear cause has been identified yet, it seems to happen randomly) the data that is written to the database via INSERT / UPDATE is not persisted but is kept in some kind of buffer: SELECTing the data shows that everything is normal and all is as it should, except when the application is closed and reopened the data is *not there*.

To further clarify the issue, here is a simplified scenario:

DAY 1

. Application is launched

. Application performs a bunch of SELECTs to query initial data for the day

. User inputs some data in the application and pushes a "SAVE" button, behind the scenes a number of INSERTs/UPDATEs are performed in the database to (apparently) persist the data.

. During the operations, all newly entered data can be worked on and shows up normally

. In the evening, user runs a feature of the application that acts as a daily summary (lots of SELECTing is involved here), they can see all the data they worked on, again all seems normal.

. Application is closed (more CRUD happening behind the scenes)

DAY 2

. Application is launched

. Application performs a bunch of SELECTs to query initial data for the day

. User can see that the initial data doesn't "sum up" with what they did the day before

. Further checking by DBAs show that a chunk of the data from yesterday just isn't there

Neither the user nor the event viewer (nor anything else) shows errors about this behavior.

I'm at a loss about where the issue could lie, scouring the internet provides very little information (maybe the tech is too old, or the issue is rare?)

I would be okay with solving the issue, obviously, with the result that data is always persisted and users are happy. I would also be okay with the application *showing an error and blocking the operation* when the data would be not persisted (whatever the cause for this is).

I welcome suggestions about what information to append to the question to aid in the resolution (the code is quite large, and I'm unsure about what is relevant).

*Expanding based on comments*

- It is difficult to know if data shows up outside of the application on DAY 1, we'd have to be constantly monitoring what's being done in the application and comparing the database (because there is no telling sign the issue is happening, no errors, nothing).
- Database permissions should not be relevant, the application works perfectly fine, then suddenly some data is lost, then again everything is fine.

Comment: On Day 1, is the data viewable outside of the application?

Comment: With that information it is difficult to know the cause. Can there be a problem with database permissions?

Comment: @BrianMStafford it's hard to know, we should be constantly monitoring every bit of data (there are no apparent errors or warnings and the application works normally... until it silently doesn't)

Comment: A more senior colleague of mine remembers some kind of mechanism that used to exist to handle loss of connectivity to the database... Seems awfully relevant (hoping it will jog people's memory?) I'm currently trying to dig up more info.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps a transaction is rolling back when the app is closed?

Comment: As @BrianMStafford suggests, this description would be consistent with your code starting a transaction but not committing it. When the app exits (actually when the db connection is closed), the server will rollback the changes. Until then, the data would be observable by that instance of the application (that connection), but would not be seen by other instances of the app (different process or workstation) - thus Brian's first question about being viewable outside of the app.

Comment: @MarkL I'm not savvy enough for this kind of diagnosis, any suggestions about steps to take in order to narrow it down ?

Comment: Search for all occurrences of keywords BeginTrans, CommitTrans and Rollback or RollbackTrans.

Comment: What to look for depends on how you're running your queries.  Transactions can be started and committed with a connection method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/begintrans-committrans-and-rollbacktrans-methods-ado?view=sql-server-ver15), or via TSQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You'll want to look for where/how you're starting a transaction, but then how you're sometimes not performing the corresponding commit. If this is what's causing your issues, of course.